# Python StockTwits Posting messages

Tags: python, json, api, stocktwits

Has no one figured this out yet??? The API docs are very confusing and poorly written. StockTwits doesn't respond. Twitter is so much easier with their API.

I have tried to make requests to get the access token. I did get one, one time. haven't been able to since. not sure what magic I did to get it. After I have the access token I tried to use

payload={"access_token":{ACCESS_TOKEN}, "body":"TEST TEST TEST"}
requests.post("http://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json", data=payload)

of course, this returns a 404 response. 
any help would be greatly greatly apprecaited.

i'm using python 3x and trying to just post messages to stocktwits.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be json, not data

```
requests.post("http://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json", json=payload)
```